# How to dissect .so file in Mac?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, decompiling

I have built an `.so` library for my Android program. Now I want to see the assembly code in that `.so` file in Mac. I tried `otool` but it outputs

> xxx.so: is not an object file

So is there any way to dissect `.so` file in Mac?

Comment: this question viewed more than 100 times, and people intention is vary. In my case why google landed me on this question is because I want to know reverse engineering and try to understand deeply about shared object in linux.